# Practical uses of the <fieldset> element (as opposed to a plain div)

Tags: html, user-interface, xhtml

I typically use divs to nest my elements.

However, Dustin Diaz mentioned using the fieldset in this article.

http://www.dustindiaz.com/focus-the-user/

When do you use fieldset instead of divs, and how does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fieldset` has semantic meaning, to hold form elements. A `div` does not have this meaning.

Also, by default, browsers can render it more suited as a form - i.e. when you use the `legend` child of `fieldset`, you can get a title for your `fieldset` rendered by the browser for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to group a set of fields (in forms).

It helps by being more explicit about what your codes doing.

I'm guessing you don't just use `span` for inline elements. Well just using `div` is analagous to doing that.

Answer (score 1):

fieldsets as the name suggest is used for collection of fields in a form. So if i have a set of fields taking user address i will collect them inside a fieldset and give fieldset a legend. Like wise if u have some categorization on ur form as personal info, education etc. You can collect the fields in fieldsets.